# wrong number of arguments(3 for 1..2) puppet

Tags: ubuntu, azure, puppet

I am trying to create a vm using puppet command . 
Here is the command :

puppet azure_vm create --azure-subscription-id=dummyid --image=dummy-image --location 'West US' --management-certificate '/home/azureuser/.puppet/modules/managementCertificate.pem' --vm-name 'test' --vm-user user01 --password abcd

After executing this command, I get an error :

wrong number of arguments(3 for 1..2)

I am not able to figure out whats causing . Can anyone  please provide any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error should be hidden in your manifest (or no more matching your puppet version) ?

- turn the trace, test and debug flag : `--trace --debug --test`